# SplitViewController And PopOverController In DetailView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I am super new to the iPad applications. I have a created a simple iPad app. MasterViewController with TableView embedded inside the UINavigationController. User taps one of the entries inside tableview that segues him to the WebViewController.

But after i implemented SplitViewController in Storyboard by telling it the Master and Detail View, the navigation bar on top of the detail view is disappeared. I have also implemented the SplitViewController that displays the master view controller on the left side in both portrait and landscape orientation but later removed it.

**What I want** is to show the masterview with tableview inside as it is with no splitviewcontroller, when user taps on one of the tableview entry, it segues to WebViewController (This is already happening till this point) but when the user reaches WebViewController, if he is in Landscape orientation, the tableview comes as a splitviewcontroller on the left side, if the user is in portrait mode, there should be a button on the navigation bar to show a popovercontroller having the same tableview entries and he can select any other entry without going back.

Can anyone help me how to implement this in Storyboards or guide me if i am doing the whole thing wrong. Thanks in advance.